# Terminology for Galois groups of non-Galois extensions.

Tags: galois-theory

I am having a confusion with terminology.  If $L/K$ is not Galois, what is the meaning of "the Galois group of $L$ over $K$"?   I have two guesses:

1) It is the field automorphisms of $L$ that fix $K$.

2) It is the Galois group of the Galois closure of $L$ over $K$.

Thanks!

Comment: There is none. You can speak of the **automorphism group** that fixes the base field, though. That is to say:  it is (1).

Comment: If you are seeing this somewhere, it would be useful if you gave an excerpt for context.

Comment: Ian Stewart, in the book *Galois Theory (third edition)*, defines the Galois group as in @user55600's item 1.  I have seen it defined as in item 2 in some Sage programs.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, (2) seems to be standard convention. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_group) defines it that way, and I have run across this and become confused before myself.

Answer (score 0):

As an example take the extension $F=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ where $\theta=\sqrt[3]{2}$, it is a field extension of degree 3 with basis $\{1, \theta, \theta^2\}$. But it is not the splitting field of $x^3-2$ (see [cubic example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field#Cubic_example)), it does not contain all the roots of $x^3-2$. Every element of the Galois group associated with this polynomial would map $F$ "outside" of F so can't be considered an automorphism of $F$. If $p$ is a polynomial having a square integer as discriminant then $F$ would be the splitting field of $p$, and the Galois group is the cyclic group of order $3$.